# Displaying a Date Variable

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

What is the best way to display the date right after it says "Creation date and time: "

```
echo "What is your name?"
read name
echo "########################################################################" > sgen.out
echo "# It was created by: " $name >> sgen.out
echo "# Creation date and time: " >> sgen.out
echo "########################################################################" >> sgen.out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put `$(date)` before your `>>` similar to where you put `$name`

```
echo "# Creation date and time: " $(date) >> sgen.out
```

or you could split that onto separate lines

```
echo -n "# Creation date and time: " >> sgen.out
date >> sgen.out
```

The `$(...)` syntax lets you execute a command and use the stdout in place similar to a variable containing that string.

Also the `date` command can take many formats if you don't like the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `date` command. 
For information on formatting the output, look at [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/) site